# useEffect infinite loop asynchronous

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks, use-effect

```
  const [allCases, setAllCases] = useState([])
  const [myCases, setMyCases] = useState([])
  const [sharedCases, setSharedCases] = useState([])
  const [favoriteCases, setFavoriteCases] = useState([])


useEffect(()=> {
    getData(_id).then(res => {
      const favoriteIds = res.data.find(i => i._id === _id).cases.map(x => {
        return x._id
      })
      setAllCases(res.cases.map(x => {
        if (favoriteIds.includes(x._id)) {
          return { ...x, isfavorite: true }
        }
        return { ...x, isfavorite: false }
      }))
      allCases && setSharedCases(allCases.filter(x => x.creator._id !== user._id))
      allCases && setMyCases(allCases.filter(x => x.creator._id === user._id))
      allCases && setFavoriteCases(allCases.filter(x => x.isfavorite))
    })

  }, [])
```

Hello, I am having problems with infinite loop. If I include brackets, my filtered cases don't populate. If i add another useEffect, I run into an infinite loop even though I am not changing allCases. (wondering why)

How can i resolve this asynchronous issue?

Comment: `allCases` won't be updated in time for you to use the values in that effect call. You'll have to use a second `useEffect`. As to why the second one was causing an infinite loop, I cant say without seeing the attempt. Were you using the array reference as a dependency maybe? `}, [allCases])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way to bypass this issue would be to call your other `useState` setters with a local variable instead of the state. Then you can update the `allCases` state with the same variable, and not have to work around async functions.

```js
useEffect(()=> {
  getData(_id).then(res => {
    const favoriteIds = res.data.find(i => i._id === _id).cases.map(x => {
      return x._id
    })

    // Save it to a local variable so that we have the value immediately
    const newAllCases = res.cases.map(x => {
      if (favoriteIds.includes(x._id)) {
        return { ...x, isfavorite: true }
      }
      return { ...x, isfavorite: false }
    })

    // Use the local variable to update state
    setSharedCases(newAllCases.filter(x => x.creator._id !== user._id))
    setMyCases(newAllCases.filter(x => x.creator._id === user._id))
    setFavoriteCases(newAllCases.filter(x => x.isfavorite))

    // Set the state for allCases
    setAllCases(newAllCases)
  })
}, [])
```

Comment: thanks! i had to edit a little by adding another useeffect and referencing allCases.

Comment: useEffect(()=> {
      setAllCases(newAllCases)
    })
  }, [])

useEffect(()=> {
  setSharedCases(allCases.filter(x => x.creator._id !== props.user._id))
  setMyCases(allCases.filter(x => x.creator._id === props.user._id))
  setFavoriteCases(allCases.filter(x => x.isfavorite))
}, [allCases])

Answer (score 0):

`allCases` within useEffect is not set before you are setting `sharedCases` and others. Also, with `[]` in `useEffect` it would only call the function on load of component. So your other state values would not get set.

I would suggest to have a separate `useEffect` with `[allCases]` and set all other values there. Something like below

```
useEffect(()=> {
    getData(_id).then(res => {
      const favoriteIds = res.data.find(i => i._id === _id).cases.map(x => {
        return x._id
      })
      setAllCases(res.cases.map(x => {
        if (favoriteIds.includes(x._id)) {
          return { ...x, isfavorite: true }
        }
        return { ...x, isfavorite: false }
      }))
    })
  }, [])

useEffect(() => {
      // do filter and set the state
}, ['allCases'])
```